# How to get around when another app incorrectly defines a UTI?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uti

This topic is mostly about iOS although it may apply to OS X as well.

I've placed a declaration in my app's `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` saying that the `.md` extension (among others) belong to UTI `net.daringfireball.markdown`. This UTI is [recommended by Markdown's initial author](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2011/08/05/markdown-uti), hence is considered canonical.

Then I used `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to open a Markdown file from Dropbox, indirectly using Dropbox's app extension. When creating that controller I specifically passed `net.daringfireball.markdown` as one of the accepted UTIs.

To my surprise the returned UTI from that action was `pro.writer.markdown`. Whereas my code was expecting `net.daringfireball.markdown` to determine whether the file returned was indeed a Markdown file. To my app, `pro.writer.markdown` wasn't recognized, and indeed it wasn't among the list of UTIs to be picked by `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

Upon further investigation, another app in my phone declares `pro.writer.markdown` in its `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` list. The app is iA Writer.

Now what would be the best way to get around this problem? These are what comes into my mind right now:

- Admit defeat and add an "or" clause to the other UTI:

  ```
  //...
  else if(UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI,@"net.daringfireball.markdown") || UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI,@"pro.writer.markdown")) {
   ... // handle Markdown file
  ```
- Fall back to the "superclass" UTI which is plain text:

  ```
  //...
  else if(UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI,@"net.daringfireball.markdown") || UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI,kUTTypePlainText)) {
   ... // handle Markdown file
  ```

The first one has the downside that I need to list down every other app's incorrect declaration of Markdown. The second one seems more plausible, but I wonder whether I am overlooking something?

Or is there a better alternative than these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to check the file extension of the selected file.

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSString *fileUTI = ...
    if ([url.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"md"] || UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, @"net.daringfireball.markdown")) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Fall back to the *plain text* UTI won't work if yet another app incorrectly claims an extension and doesn't setup the UTI hierarchy correctly. In any case the filename extension is the canonical source to determine type when the file was obtained from foreign file systems.